# getting syntax error at line 4 in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Create Table ITEM (
  ItemID Char(25) Not Null
, ItemName Char(25) Not Null
, ItemPrice Decimal(5, 2) Not Null
, QuantityonHand Int Not Null
, Primary Key (ItemID)
);
```

Comment: So whats a bit different in that line?

Comment: Works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cb302

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this,

```
Create Table ITEM (
 ItemID Char(25) Not Null PRIMARY KEY,
 ItemName Char(25) Not Null,
 ItemPrice Decimal(5, 2) Not Null,
 QuantityonHand Int Not Null
);
```

Comment: Glad to help. But not sure what was the purpose of downgrading my answer.

Comment: I didn't, it was at -2 and I kept trying to upvote it.

Comment: But I am not sure why yours was having problem as that worked for me too.

Comment: I guess I am just buggy, sorry for confusion. I wouldn't downvote someone who helped me!

Comment: I know you didn't but the question was for those users who downvoted.